# I have an error with my asp gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

I want my emails to be read into a Grid view, but i keep getting an error and i have no idea why?

This is the code that i have used to insert my grid view, but when i hit run it fails.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="From" DataField="From" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Subject" DataNavigateUrlFields="MessageNumber" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/webFormShow.aspx?MessageNumber={0}"
            DataTextField="ubject" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="DateSent" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is really strange considering i copied this code from one of my working programs??

The error below is all the info they give me

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.displaymaillist_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.displaymaillist_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am i doing wrong??

They did not give me much info, so i can only provide this little bit :( but i sure hope someone can help.

Comment: The error says it all - you have OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged" but in your code behind you do not have a method gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged to handle the event.

Comment: do you have **gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged** in your **c#** code??

Comment: Oh jea ok checked my old project, and i have a blank gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged{}, really did not think it would be important if its empty, but it works now, thanks guys, i sat the whole day on such a silly thing .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged"** remove it from your aspx or add the event in the cs class. This exception occurs when code is missing from code behind.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler `gvEmails_SelectedIndexChanged` needs to exist in the code behind of the file - have you copied that part as well?

If you select the grid in the designer then from the events window you should be able to double click the SelectedIndexChanged event and it will get generated for you (I can't remember if it does this for ASPX pages, but if you type it directly in the ASPX page then the designer may also auto-complete for you).

Comment: Thanks guys u nailed first time :D don't need any more answers